# Twilio: Mute a participant in a conference

Tags: twilio

I'm building a mobile voice conference application using Twilio SDK.
I need to implement a mute button so a user could temporary block an incoming voice track of a specific participant. But other users in a conference should be able to hear the muted user ofc. Just like a mute button in the Skype.

Yet I have no luck in finding a solution. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Not 100% clear on the scenario Bob, Alice and Jane are in a conference.  You want Bob to be able to mute Alice so he cannot hear here, but Alice and Jane can still hear each other?

Comment: @DevinRader, yes, exactly.

Comment: Alice and Jane can still hear each other and Bob too.
So when Bob mutes Alice then Jane can hear Alice, Alice can hear Bob, Jane can hear Bob but Bob can't hear only Alice.

Comment: Pretty sure Twilio does not support selective muting in a conference like that.  If Bob mutes Alice, then no one in the conference call will be able to hear here.  Maybe if you explain a bit more broadly what you want to explain I can help figure out a solution.

Comment: @DevinRader, I need to be able to mute a participant in a conference locally. So a client may receive an audio track on a device but won't hear it.

Comment: Its selective muting but only locally on a client.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is using Twilio Client?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client - this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123717/discussion-between-mehdzor-and-devin-rader).

Comment: @DevinRader Any ideas?