# With twilio: Mute a specific participant in a room

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I made a lot of searches, and tried many things. Let's take the same scenario from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551921/twilio-mute-a-participant-in-a-conference).

**Bob, Alice, and Jane** are in a conference. I want **Bob** (the hoster of the room) to be able to mute **Alice** so sounds from **Alice** will not come through the room, but **Alice** still hear sounds from all other participants (**Bob & Jane**)

Imagine the scenario when you are in conference, and someone disturbs the Live. So I want the hoster to be able to mute or remove the audio track of that person.

So far, I can mute the audio tracks for the local participant with:

```
$(document).on("click",'.mute-audio',function(){
    if(room){
        let microEnabled = true;
        microEnabled = !microEnabled;
        room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(audioTrack) {
            audioTrack.enable(microEnabled);
        });
    }
});
```

We simply iterate through audioTracks of the local participant, and if I want to do so for a specific User, I just need to know his `identity` and I am good to go:

```
$(document).on("click",'.mute-user',function(){
    var identity = $(this).data('identity'); // i.e the unique ID USER2323
    if(room){
        var user_to_mute;


        room.participants.audioTracks.forEach(function(participant) {
            audioTrack.enable(microEnabled);
            user_to_mute = participant;
            // We retrieve the target
            return;
        });

        let m_Enabled = true;
        m_Enabled = !m_Enabled;
        if(user_to_mute){
            user_to_mute.audioTracks.forEach(function(audioTrack) {
                audioTrack.enable(m_Enabled);
                // the error is here I think
                return;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, when I try I got this error from the browser

```
TypeError: audioTrack.enable is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some copy paste errors to me, but not being familiar with the API, I'm making a few assumptions:

```
$(document).on("click",'.mute-user',function(){
  var identity = $(this).data('identity'); // i.e the unique ID USER2323
  if(room){
    var user_to_mute;
    // in the next line, we remove .audioTracks, since it looks like
    // you want to iterate over participants, and removed audioTrack.enable
    // since it's not defined yet
    room.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
        if (identity == participant.identity) {
            // We retrieve the target
            user_to_mute = participant;
            return;
        }
    });

    let m_Enabled = true;
    m_Enabled = !m_Enabled;
    if(user_to_mute){
        user_to_mute.audioTracks.forEach(function(audioTrack) {
            audioTrack.enable(m_Enabled);
            return;
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: No it's not a copy/paste. this should work. `room.participants.forEach(function(participant) {` will iterate a participants array, when i get the `participant.identity` that mactches the code. I assign it to `user_to_mute`. and then I loop through `user_to_mute.audioTracks` and then **enable/disable** the `audio` as clearly mentioned in doc. It seems that this option is only available for local participant, not for remote participants